# What are "user units" in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, units

I created a drawing whilst learning to use Inkscape and didn't pay any attention to the units I used. When it came to saving the drawing as an image, I decided I wanted the the image to be of the whole page and that the image should be 1920x1200 pixels. Here is my drawing and what I believe are the relevant settings:

[image: Inkscape settings for 1920x1200 image]

Inkscape says the viewbox is 508 by 317.5 in "user units" but I don't recognise the numbers 508 and 317.5. I can see that 508 = 1920*xs where xs is the x scaling factor (0.24565) but I didn't knowingly choose "508" or "0.24565" - where did they come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, user units are **mm** at 96dpi.

The default document template in Inkscape uses mm as unit for typing out values in the XML code (the text file that holds the SVG data).

You must at some point have changed both the 'Display unit' as well as the unit for the document size, to px.

Display unit is what is used in the dialogs and number fields in Inkscape per default.

Convert px to inch:
1920px / 96 dots per inch = 20 inch

Convert inch to mm:
20 inch * (25.4 mm per inch) = 508 mm

More info at:
http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Units_In_Inkscape

Comment: Did you mean (20 inch * 25.4 mm per inch) = 508 mm?

Comment: Yep, thanks @davidvandebunte!